# Extract data using spring jdbctemplate to load in a different database

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate

I need to extract data from some random tables from my database, and insert into similar tables in a different database.

I am not clear as to how I can write a generic method which can handle all the tables.

```
this.jdbcTemplate.query("select * from TableName", new RowMapper() {
         @Override
         public Object mapRow(ResultSet resultSet, int i) throws SQLException {
             while(resultSet.next()){
//                Fetch data in a generic object for later updating in a different schema
             }
             return null;  //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
         }
     });
```

Comment: Please define what you mean by 'similar tables' - do they have the same structure and the only difference is the database they are in or does the structure differ?

Comment: Same structure. For eg I have tables A, B, C in DB1 which all have different structure, and I need to archive these tables to DB2 which has tables A, B and C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be honest, `JdbcTemplate` isn't the best choice for this sort of task.  You'll need to do some one-time processing of the `ResultSet` to create the insert SQL and there's not really any point you can do this using `JdbcTemplate` (as far as I know).

Anyway, this is how I'd do the copy you want in pure JDBC (you can take the same principles and squeeze it into `JdbcTemplate` if you want to):

```
Connection sourceConnection = null; 
Connection destinationConnection = null; 

PreparedStatement selectStatement = null;
PreparedStatement insertStatement = null;

ResultSet resultSet = null;

try
{
  sourceConnection = ...
  destinationConnection = ...

  selectStatement = sourceConnection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM table");
  resultSet = selectStatement.executeQuery();

  insertStatement = destinationConnection.prepareStatement(createInsertSql(resultSet.getMetaData()));

  int batchSize = 0;
  while (resultSet.next())
  {
    setParameters(insertStatement, resultSet);
    insertStatement.addBatch();
    batchSize++;

    if (batchSize >= BATCH_EXECUTE_SIZE)
    {
      insertStatement.executeBatch();
      batchSize = 0;  
    }
  }

  insertStatement.executeBatch();
}
finally 
{
  JdbcUtils.closeResultSet(resultSet);

  JdbcUtils.closeStatement(insertStatement);
  JdbcUtils.closeStatement(selectStatement);

  JdbcUtils.closeConnection(destinationConnection);
  JdbcUtils.closeConnection(sourceConnection);
}
```

The important bit is what happens in the `createInsertSql` and `setParameters` methods, which both use the `ResultSetMetaData` to perform their operations.  You'll need to play with these a bit depending on the database you're using but they'll look something like:

```
private String createInsertSql(ResultSetMetaData resultSetMetaData) throws SQLException
{
  StringBuffer insertSql = new StringBuffer("INSERT INTO ");
  StringBuffer values = new StringBuffer(" VALUES (");

  insertSql.append(resultSetMetaData.getTableName());

  for (int i = 1; i <= resultSetMetaData.getColumnCount(); i++)
  {
    insertSql.append(resultSetMetaData.getColumnName(i));
    values.append("?");

    if (i <= resultSetMetaData.getColumnCount())
    {
      insertSql.append(", ");
      values.append(", ");
    }
    else 
    {
      insertSql.append(")");
      values.append(")");
    }
  }

  return insertSql.toString() + values.toString();
}
```

And:

```
private void setParameters(PreparedStatement preparedStatement, ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException
{
  for (int i = 1; i <= resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++)
  {
    preparedStatement.setObject(i, resultSet.getObject(i)); 
  }  
}
```

Note this only works if the source and destination databases have identically structured tables.  If they vary you'll have to start defining mappings between the two, at which point you're better off just buying an ETL tool.

**Following Comment**

The insert/update thing is quite a lot harder.

From the `DatabaseMetaData` you'd need to get the primary key and query both the source and destination tables making sure the query orders by the primary key columns.

Then as you iterate over the source result set you'd need to check the destination result set to see if the primary key columns match or are greater in ordering, creating insert or update sql accordingingly.

For example if you had simple integer keys in the source table 1, 2, 3, 4, 7 and in the destination table you had 1, 2, 4, 5, 6 then:

- 1 = update
- 2 = update
- 3 because it's before 4 can safely be an insert
- 4 = update
- 7 you need to iterate the destination result set until you've gone past 6 before you can know for certain that 7 is an insert.

Sorry if that's not that clear, it's hard to explain in static text.

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly if I need to insert the records in the destination table. I also need to keep a check, if the record with same primary key already exist in the destination table, I need to update rather than insert.

Comment: See explanation of how to do insert or update in the section titled **Following Comment** above.

Answer (score 0):

Call the

```
this.jdbcTemplate.setDateSource(sourceDB)
```

before read data

and

```
this.jdbcTemplate.setDateSource(targetDB)
```

before writing.

Register multiple DataSources in your spring and use something like this

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("writeDataSource")
public void setDataSource(DataSource writeDataSource) {
    this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(writeDataSource);
}
```

Comment: How is this going to help with copying the data between the two databases (other than you obviously need two connections)?

Comment: Exactly I know how I will configure multiple datasources using spring. But how to extract the data in a generic way when the tables from which I want to fetch data are different.